# Refer to line number in note

Tags: article, todonotes, lineno

I want to add comments to a manuscript and refer to the line number I am commenting about. Is it possible to do that?

I am using the standard **article** class, package **lineno** for numbering the lines and package **todonotes** to add notes and create a list of "todos" (\listoftodos). Solutions involving other packages are also accepted.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that is a compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you! Next time I will add a MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from package `lineno` documentation, p. 12:

> `lineno.sty` allows to refer to a line number with `\ref{<label>}`.
>   The label is set by `\linelabel{<label>}`, anywhere in a paragraph
>   that gets line numbers.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{mwe}% just for testing purpose

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\blindtext % this command only print some casual text

Labelled line.\linelabel{lne:label1}\todo{This is a todonote at line \lineref{lne:label1}.}

\blindtext

Another labelled line.\linelabel{lne:label2}\todo{This is another todonote at line \lineref{lne:label2}.}

\blindtext

\listoftodos[Notes]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be done without all the line numbers showing?

Comment: @RichardBirkett Of course, just leave out `\usepackage{lineno}` and `\linenumbers`